# Handling repeating rows fetched through join in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two tables

```
 1-products
 --------
 product_id
 product_name

 2-product_images
 --------------
 image_id
 product_id
 product_image
```

Now I have multiple images for one product. Means there are multiple records for in product_images table for single product_id.

When I execute this query

```
 $products = Product::join('product_images AS pi', 'pi.product_id', 'products.product_id')
 ->get();
```

This results in getting multiple rows for same product due to join. Now how do I handle that in spite of many images for single product, just one row should be fetched or shown. I can do it through Laravel but I want to learn handling through database. If can, help.

Comment: `->groupBy('pi.product_id');`

Comment: using `distinct()` ?

Comment: Suppose there are three rows for one product. Now which row you want to fetch from First to 3rd

Comment: Any one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

->groupBy('products.product_id')